# why is nothing appear on the screen just the background while displaying a profile information as list view?

Tags: java, android

i want to make user profile like the one in the image ,but when i run the application nothing appear on the screen  just the background appear  what is the problem ?
why the list view item ( the two text views and the image view) not appear

this is my code:

this is the first xml file" profile.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/color_white" >



 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/list_holder" android:paddingTop="20dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="0.0dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip" >
    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/profile_list" android:paddingTop="5dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="4.0dip" android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginLeft="6.0dip" android:layout_marginRight="6.0dip" 
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:divider="@drawable/list_divider" android:dividerHeight="1.0dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the second " profile_row.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/profile_row" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="50.0dip">

<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1.0">
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_image"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />
    <TextView 
        android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ff000000" 
        android:gravity="left|center" android:id="@+id/row_data" 
        android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip" android:layout_weight="0.5" />

     <TextView 
        android:gravity="right|center" android:id="@+id/row_txt" 
        android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip" android:layout_weight="0.4" style="@style/Text.profileRow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

```
       public class ProfileView extends Activity
      {
     private List<String> adapterList;
 private ListView mList;
 private ProfileAdapter mProfileAdapter;

              @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

   mList = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.profile_list));

   initFixedList();
   initAdapter();
   mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)          {
           // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you are clicked"+position,
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     });




   }


   private void initFixedList()
   {
       this.adapterList = new ArrayList<String>();
       this.adapterList.add("name");
       this.adapterList.add("age");
       this.adapterList.add("height");
       this.adapterList.add("weight");
       this.adapterList.add("Activity level");
    }

    class ProfileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
      {   
   Context context; 
                 int layoutResourceId;    
       private TextView rowData;
       private ImageView rowImage;
        private TextView rowTxt;

    public ProfileAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId) 
       {
       super(context, layoutResourceId);
       this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       this.context = context; 
        }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       if(row == null)
       {
           row=        ProfileView.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.profile_row,parent,false);
           this.rowImage = ((ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_image));
           this.rowData = ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_data));
           this.rowTxt = ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_txt));

       }
       else
       row = convertView;
       int j;
       if ((position != 0) || (getCount() <= 0))
           j = 0;
         else
           j = 1;
         int i;
         if ((position != getCount() - 1) || (getCount() <= 0))
           i = 0;
         else
           i = 1;
         RelativeLayout localRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.profile_row);
         if (j == 0)
         {
           if (i == 0)
             localRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_gradient_selector );

           else
               localRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_gradient_bottom_selector );
         }
         else
           localRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_gradient_top_selector );

       switch (position)
       {
         case 0:
         this.rowData.setText(StaticPreferences.getName(this));
         break;
         case 1:
           this.rowData.setText(StaticPreferences.getAge(this));
           break;
         case 2:
             this.rowData.setText(StaticPreferences.getHeight(this));
             break;
         case 3:
             this.rowData.setText(StaticPreferences.getWeight(this));
             break;
         case 4:
             this.rowData.setText(StaticPreferences.getActivityLevel(this));
             break;

       }
       this.rowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
       this.rowTxt.setText((CharSequence)ProfileView.this.adapterList.get(position));
       return row;
   }
```

}

private void initAdapter()
   {

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
 {
   public void run()
   {
     ProfileView.this.mProfileAdapter = null;
     ProfileView.this.mProfileAdapter = new     ProfileView.ProfileAdapter(ProfileView.this,R.layout.profile_row);
     ProfileView.this.mList.setAdapter(ProfileView.this.mProfileAdapter);
     ProfileView.this.mProfileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
 });
```

}
}

Comment: I don't see why it would be empty but you don't need to `runOnUiThread()` if you call `initAdapter()` in `onCreate` since you are already on the UI thread there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the [getCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount%28%29) method in ArrayAdapter so you can specify the number of records in your adapter. Currently the getCount method will return 0 and display 0 records on the page. Additionally, you should be using a [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) since you aren't using an ArrayAdapter as it was designed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set adapter everytime you want to load the ListView.
Check if the listview already has an adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged().

```
if(ProfileView.this.mList.getAdapter() == null){
    ProfileView.this.mList.setAdapter(ProfileView.this.mProfileAdapter);
}
else{
     ProfileView.this.mProfileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**XML EDIT:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/profile_row" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="50.0dip">

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />
    <TextView 
        android:textSize="14.0sp" android:textColor="#ff000000" 
        android:gravity="left|center" android:id="@+id/row_data" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

     <TextView 
        android:gravity="right|center" android:id="@+id/row_txt" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried what you say but the problem still . nothing appear on the screen

Comment: I see that you are trying to set the text in the switch case. Can you try adding Log.i() statements to make sure staticPreferences.getName(this) returns data.

Comment: ok , but why the image view and the adapter List strings not appear on the screen ?

Comment: If you believe they are independent of data, then you might want to check the layout files.

Comment: Did you print the data correctly using the log statement? In the layout files, you may not have correctly set the views. (might be hiding or length might not have been set). Can you post the layout xml files.

Comment: i tried all the things you talked about and the problem still, why is that ?please help me ,its very important for me to understand and solve the problem , can you post to me the correct solution for making the information appear as a list view?